# Using jquery .data() assignment in asp.net loop

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

this might be a stupid question,

but I'm using asp.net list control that creates a table with `<div>` elements that have a picture thumbnail, and when the user clicks on the div and it calls Ajax method and populates a shared dialog with correct information, and then shows it to the user. In order to do this the div needs to know the item id associated with it, so it can do the db lookup.

Right now I'm doing stuff like `<div id="item<% Eval(Id) %>Widget" onmouseover="GetInfo(<% Eval(Id) %>"` and then the `GetInfo(id)` method does so work to look up information and show and hide the appropriate elements to the user, etc. I recently read about the jquery `.data()` method and that sounds like a cleaner solution, because ideally in my `<itemtemplate>` I would  associate the id with div tag (as its being written), that way the id doesn't show up in the source (i.e `GetInfo(5)`) ( this is not a big deal, as i don't care too much that user can see this id), but my secondary and biggest motivation is to be able to bind a click method by class name rather then id, so ideally something like `$(".itemWidget).hover(func (show/hide stuff));`

So my questions boils down to, how do you dynamically store data to a div item in a list view loop.

so something like

```
<listControl>
  <ItemTemplate>
    < div>
       stuff
       thisdiv.data(<% Eval(id) %>); // <-unsure about this part
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</listControl>
```

**Thanks for any help you can provide!**

Comment: my initial thoughts are to do something like <div> <script> $(this).data(id); </script> </div>, not sure if this can or will work

Comment: That won't work, what is "this" in that context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [HTML5 custom data attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes).  You can include them into the markup like this...

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <div class="whatever" data-id="<%= Eval(id) %>">
   stuff
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

And then with jQuery (1.4.3 and above) you can easily get at it using [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) like this...

```
$(".whatever").hover(
  function() {
    //show
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    alert(id);
    GetInfo(id);
  },
  function() {
    //hide
  }
);
```

Comment: +1 For use of `$.data()` to read the data- attribute.  Didn't know that :)

Comment: what about older browsers (non html 5)?

Comment: Older browsers simply ignore the attributes.

Comment: @Nate No.  Custom attributes have always been ignored, and no forms of "invalid markup" will stop the browser from attempting to render.

Comment: but would older browsers be able to get at the data attribute.

Comment: @Nate See the [jQuery Browser Compaitibility](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility) docs

Comment: when i run this I get undefined, for id.

Answer (score 1):

This actually seems more like a job for the [new data- attributes in HTML5](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <div data-id="<%# Eval("id") %>" class="itemWidget">
      stuff       
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then your jQuery code could:

```
 $(".itemWidget").hover(function () {
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
 })
```

Comment: This one works as well, and is actually what I'm using at the moment, however the above example, is probably the better way to do it long term. Thanks for the help.